# AWS ALB using path-based and port-based routing at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have two apps in ECS configured to expose different ports (app1 at 3000 and app2 at 8080). I would like to expose app1 at the endpoint `https://<alb dns name>/app1` and the other at `http://<alb dns name>:8080`.

I've configured an https listener with a certificate and set the path to point to the app1's target group. Then I setup a port 8080 http listener to route to app2's target group. App1 resolves fine at the path, however requests to app2 time out.

I have verified that both apps are accessible to the alb (and both show healthy in their TGs). If I configure app2 to use path-based routing I can connect to it (however I don't want to do that; app2 needs to be served from `/`). If i configure the http 8080 listener to just return a fixed response, it still times out (does not return the response). I'm unable to remove the https listener to test, as that's a production app with a uptime guarantee. For testing I added a ALL/0.0.0.0/0 SG to both the ALB and both apps.

Is this a rule of ALBs that I'm unaware of (can't do both at the same time), or an I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, but just to test I added a SG with ALL/0.0.0.0/0 to the LB and both apps, nothing different.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you already did, but you need to update the ECS service of app2, in ‘Configure ELB’ section, select application load balancer in ELB type section,
select your new **listener port**, ALB & target group.

Comment: I did configure the ECS container to use the listener, and in the ECS console service details under "load balancer" it shows the correct Target group, container name, and container port.